# android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar does not work properly

Tags: java, android, toolbar

[image]

as you can toolbar is not displayed correctly in the design section. and Its size is unalterable. The attribute set for it are not displayed in the design field. attribute like background , color and ...

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="49dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: move your cursor on top of the ( ! ) sign, so you can see the error.

Comment: may I see the Text of your xml file?

Comment: @fatemeh fallahi arezoudar : added xml file

Comment: remove these lines `tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="49dp"`

Comment: @fatemeh fallahi arezoudar :  مشکل حل نشد من انگلیسیم خوب نیست مشکلم اینجاست که تغییر کد اصلا تو قسمت طراحی گرافیکی تغییری به وجود نمیارن و اصلا نمی تونی ظاهر گرافیکی رو تغییر بدی اما وقتی برنامه اجرا میشه تغییرات کد تو ایمولیتور نمایش داده میشه. همنجوری که تو تصویر می بینید به همون اندازه می مونه و اصلا تغییری نمی کنه و فقط جا به جا میشه یا نهایتا وقتی حالت رپ کانتنت هم میزنی به صورت یک خطی میشه.

Comment: in Android Studio  go to File> Invalid cache/Restart > Invalidate and Restart

Comment: @fatemeh fallahi arezoudar : نه متاسفانه هنوز هم مشکل حل نشد.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this for my projects and works :

as first you must add this style in your style file in res

```
<style name="ToolBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

in activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/ToolBarMain"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

then be sure that your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` is not = 28 and like this for example:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.yasin.taksmssender"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Styles.xml**
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">` *add this*

**MainActivity.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/appbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/green">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
Toolabar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appbar);

setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Name on Toolabar");
        mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```